# Codemirror and iFrame issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using Codemirror in one of my project.
Here the code :

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var te = document.getElementById("js");
var te_html = document.getElementById("html");
var te_css = document.getElementById("css");

window.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te, {
mode: "javascript",
    lineWrapping: true,
    });

 window.editor_css = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te_css, {
    mode: "css",
    lineWrapping: true,
    });

  window.editor_html = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te_html, {
    mode: "text/html",
    lineWrapping: true,
  })
};
</script>
```

I'm also using Jeffrey Way's "How to Inject Custom HTML and CSS into an iframe" script to build something similar to Tinkerbin, or JSFiddle.

Here's my code for that part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    $('.grid').height( $(window).height() );    

    var contents = $('iframe').contents(),
    body = contents.find('body'),
    styleTag = $('<style></style>').appendTo(contents.find('head'));

    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.attr('id') === 'html') 
        {
        body.html( $this.val() );
        } 
        else 
        {
        styleTag.html( $this.val() );
        }

    });

})();
</script>
```

It's all fine, except that with the CodeMirror script activated, nothing shows up in the RESULT tab. And if I delete the CodeMirror code part, it works fine.

Here's my project link :

http://mediodesign.ca/cms-test/

Anybody knows where is the conflict?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have loaded all the javascripts

```
mode/javascript.js
mode/css.js
mode/xml.js
```

and if you are using this script inside an xhtml file. use single quotes(`'`) instead of double quotes(`"`)

ex.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var te = document.getElementById('js');
var te_html = document.getElementById('html');
var te_css = document.getElementById('css');

window.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te, {
mode: 'javascript',
    lineWrapping: true,
    });

 window.editor_css = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te_css, {
    mode: 'css',
    lineWrapping: true,
    });

  window.editor_html = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(te_html, {
    mode: 'text/html',
    lineWrapping: true,
  })
};
</script>
```

Jeffrey Way's *How to Inject Custom HTML and CSS into an iframe*... is irrelevant of loading the codemirror script